# Textview Click Issue Android

Tags: android, click, textview, cpu-word, marquee

I have a textview as "emy wattson is a student" and I used marquee property for this textview. Now, it is sliding text. Now, I want to know the clicked word. For example, now I can click the all text and when I want to write the clicked text, I see "emy wattson is a student". But I want to know "emy" , "wattson" , "is" ... seperatly. So, how can I click just word???? Please,help me.

Comment: Maybe you can use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#getSelectionStart%28%29 and getSeletionEnd() but I don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...I'm not sure how this would be done. Since a TextView is just an instance of a String, the only way(that I know of) to extract specific values and indexes from String is to use indexOf() and subString() methods. What are you trying to do after you've determined which word in the TextView was clicked?

Comment: Now I have a database , I take the words in the database and show them  as sliding text.When the user click a word , I want to show the meaning of the word with taking from database.

Comment: For example there is a game for iphone : http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/fishtropolis-word-fun-for/id348631081?mt=8 there are some words on the screen. They are sliding and clickable. I want to do this!!